# Attempting to create a FAT file system in C++?

Tags: c++, filesystems, fat

I'm attempting to create a FAT file system I understand the basic principle of how its supposed to set up and I'm using a struct like this for each FAT entry

```
struct FATEntry
{
    char      name[20];  /* Name of file */
    uint32_t  pos;       /* Position of file on disk (sector, block, something else) */
    uint32_t  size;      /* Size in bytes of file */
    uint32_t  mtime;     /* Time of last modification */
};
```

I'm essentially creating a 2 MB file to act as my file system. From there I will write and read files into blocks of 512 bytes each. My question how I can write a struct to a file? Does fwrite allow me to do this? For example:

```
struct FATEntry entry1;
strcpy(entry1.name, "abc");
entry1.pos = 3;
entry1.size = 10;
entry1.mtime = 100;
cout << entry1.name;

file = fopen("filesys", "w");
fwrite(&entry1,sizeof(entry1),1,file);
fclose(file);
```

Will that store the struct in bytes? How do I read from this? I'm having trouble understanding what I will get back when I use fread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will that store the struct in bytes?

- yes. in C++ you will need to explicitly cast `&entry1` to `(void*)`

How do I read from this?

- `fread((void*)&entry1,sizeof(entry1),1,file);`

(but don't forget "r" flag to `fopen()`)

The real problem in your case is that the struct [will probably be padded by the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing), for efficient access. so you will have to use `__attribute__((packed))` if you are using gcc.

[EDIT]
code sample (C, not C++):

```
struct FATEntry entry1 { "abc", 3, 10, 100 };
FILE* file1 = fopen("filesys", "wb");
fwrite(&entry1, sizeof(struct FATEntry), 1, file1);
fclose(file1)

struct FATEntry entry2 { "", 0, 0, 0 };
FILE* file2 = fopen("filesys", "rb");
fread(&entry2, sizeof(struct FATEntry), 1, file2;
fclose(file2)
```

You can now check that you read what you have written earlier:

```
assert(memcmp(&entry1, &entry2, sizeof(struct FATEntry))==0);
```

the [assert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) will fail if the read or the write did not succeed (I didn't check for this).

Comment: Thank you but what does fread((void*)&entry1,sizeof(entry1),1,file); return? A struct? I think that is what is confusing me.

Comment: [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) returns "The total number of elements successfully read". which might be less than what you meant. It will fill `entry1` with the actual data.

Comment: oops - I forgot to mention you'll need to use the "b" flag too - You are working with raw data, not text.